# Add grouped rows

Tags: sql, database

I have a database table with customers which contains each of their ages, among other things.

I want to query the customers and sort them into age groups for a result like this:

```
Age_Group   Num_Of_Cust 
 0-10        Count 
 10-20       Count 
 20-30       Count
```

Is this possible to do in a single query?  I essentially want to insert table row values and count the number of people in that age group in the second column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple `case` statement does the trick:

```
select agegroup, count(*)
from (select (case when age <= 10 then '00-10'
                   when age <= 20 then '11-20'
                   when age <= 30 then '21-30'
                   else '31+'
              end) as agegreoup, t.*
      from t
     ) t
group by agegroup
```

I've included a final group for everyone else (and assumed that ages are never negative).  Also, I used '00-10' rather than '0-10' so all the group name have the same length.  The subquery is not strictly necessary.  I find it more readable.

Answer (score 2):

Try something like

```
select age / 10, count(*) from table_name group by age / 10 order by age / 10;
```

This will give you a result with rows containing first the tens column of the ages grouped and then the number in that range. The range will actually be 0-9, 10-19, etc.; if you want to shift it up one you can replace `age` with `(age-1)`. Note that it will also skip ranges containing no customers.

To more exactly reproduce the requested output - but may not work in all RDBMS (tested on PostgreSQL), the following can be used:

```
select concat(Age*10, '-', Age*10+9) as Age_Group, Num_of_Cust from (
    select age / 10 as Age, count(*) as Num_Of_Cust from test
        group by age / 10 order by age / 10) as X;
```

(I don't like the subselect but it seems necessary to get the right ordering and labels. Ordering by `Age_Group` itself puts, say, 100-109 before 20-29. Trying to cast `Age_Group` has PostgreSQL protesting that it's not a column. The final `as X` was also needed to eliminate a complaint that the subquery needs an alias.)

Comment: You seem to be assuming that the division is integral in this case. It might be a good idea to specify that explicitly in your answer.

Comment: It seems all common databases will assume that except (sigh) MySQL. I couldn't find if it was SQL standard. MySQL can use "DIV" to force integer division.

Comment: Oracle is a fairly common database that also does floating point division.

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this:

```
SELECT
  Coalesce(case when age<10 then '0-9' end,
           case when age between 10 and 20 then '10-20' end,
           case when age>20 then '>20' end) As Age_Group,
  Count(*)
From your_table
Group by Age_Group
```

Comment: @RichardTheKiwi some DMBS other than MySql don't support alias in group by clause, so you have to substitute `group by Age_Group` with `group by coalesce(...`, it doesn't look good but it should work